# return/break a function from the derived base class

Tags: scala

In my REST API service layer, I have a class ProductService.
The following *logic* exists in all my functions: Do Validate, if validation fails i throw invalid exception, if passes, i continue to the next try-catch and throw general-error in case of failure:

```
def addProduct(request:AddProductRequest): BaseResponse[String] = 
{
  try
  {
      request.validate
  }
  catch
  {
     case ex: Exception => {
       Logger.error("Failed to add product, Validation failed", ex);
       val errorResponse:ErrorResponse[String] = new ErrorResponseList().InvalidParameters
       errorResponse.addMessage(ex.getMessage)
       return errorResponse
     }
  }

  try
  {
      val addedProductId = productRepository.addProduct(request.language, request.tenantId, request.product)
      DTOResponse(addedProductId)      
  }
  catch
  {    
     case ex: Exception => {
       Logger.error("Failed to add product to tenant Id="+request.tenantId+" language="+request.language, ex);
       val errorResponse:ErrorResponse[String] = new ErrorResponseList().GeneralError
       errorResponse.addMessage(ex.getMessage())
       return errorResponse
     }
  }
}
```

Now, instead of repeating the request.validate with the same try and catch for all functions, i created a base class with the following function:

```
abstract class ServiceBase {
def validate[T](request:BaseRequest)
{
  try
  {
    request.validate
  }
  catch
  {
    case ex: Exception => {
      Logger.error("Validation failed", ex);
      val errorResponse:ErrorResponse[String] = new ErrorResponseList().InvalidParameters
      errorResponse.addMessage(ex.getMessage)
      return errorResponse
    }
  }
}
```

So now, my addProduct(..) will look like:

```
validate(request)
..the rest of the code - the 2nd try-catch
```

This saves alot of lines.

The problem is that if validation fails, it will never return. I get the following errors in ServiceBase:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- enclosing method validate has result type Unit: return value discarded
- enclosing method validate has result type Unit: return value discarded
- a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary 
 parentheses
```

Answer (score 1):

`validate` has no return type (and thus defaults to returning `Unit`), in `ServiceBase` your signature for `validate` should look like this:

```
def validate[T](request:BaseRequest): BaseResponse[String] =
```

(assuming you want to return a `BaseResponse[String]`)

Comment: Thanks, in addition to the return of BaseResponse it must be Option as well.

Answer (score 0):

this may be useful to someone, someday, functional programming.. Did we say ^_^

Changed the ServiceBase validate to:

```
def validate[T](request:BaseRequest):Option[BaseResponse[T]] =
{
  try
  {
    request.validate
    None
  }
  catch
  {
    case ex: Exception => {
      Logger.error("Validation failed", ex);
      val errorResponse:ErrorResponse[T] = new ErrorResponseList().InvalidParameters
      errorResponse.addMessage(ex.getMessage)
      return Some(errorResponse)
    }
  }
}
```

And now i do:

```
def getProducts(request:GetProductsRequest) :BaseResponse[ProductSearchResults] = 
{      
  validate[ProductSearchResults](request).getOrElse(
      {
        try
        {
          val products = productRepository.getProducts(request.language,request.tenantId,request.productIds)
          val foundProducts = for (product <- products) yield  (product.id)
          val notFoundProducts = request.productIds filterNot (foundProducts.toSet)
          val responseWrapper = new ProductSearchResults(products, notFoundProducts)
          DTOResponse(responseWrapper)
        }
        catch
        {
          case ex: Exception => {
            Logger.error("Failed to get products from tenant Id="+request.tenantId+" language="+request.language, ex);
            val errorResponse:ErrorResponse[ProductSearchResults] = new ErrorResponseList().GeneralError
            errorResponse.addMessage(ex.getMessage())
            return errorResponse
            }
        }})
 }
```